# How to load DrawingVisuals asynchronously with Async and Await?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I use a Canvas as host for thousands of DrawingVisuals. Loading is very slow. I tried to load only the at start visible DrawingVisuals and with async and await the other DrawingVisuals:

```
Async Sub AddVisuals()
    Dim visuals = Await Task.Run(AddressOf CreateVisuals)
    For Each vis In visuals
        AddVisualChild(vis)
        AddLogicalChild(vis)
    Next
End Sub
Function CreateVisuals() As DrawingVisual()
    ....
End Function
```

But Task.Run calls another thread. So I get an InvalidOperation exception stating that the object is owned by another thread.
But [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh191443.aspx) I find:

> The async and await keywords **don't cause additional threads** to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process that's just waiting for results to become available.

So, is there a way to add a DispatcherObject (here: DrawingVisual) with async and await?

Comment: As I use Visual Studio 2010 I haven't worked with async/await, but wouldn't `Dim visuals = Await CreateVisuals()` do the trick? Or just `Dim visuals = CreateVisuals()` since CreateVisuals() should block the current thread until it returns.

Comment: But I don't want to block the current thread. Drawing  all visuals takes too long and blocks the UI.

Comment: Then why are you using `Await`?

Comment: I want the not currently visible DrawingVisuals - later they can become visible by scrolling - to be loaded in background without blocking the UI.

Comment: Then you would have to remove the function and loop the code that creates them in the first place. In the end of that code before it starts creating the next visual you call `AddVisualChild()` and `AddLogicalChild()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal of "I want the not currently visible DrawingVisuals - later they can become visible by scrolling - to be loaded in background without blocking the UI", I suggest you try using UI Virtualization instead of Async...Await.

Set the container control's IsItemsHost property to True, and then you can set the ItemsPanel property to VirtualizingStackPanel and set IsVirtualizing to true.

Read more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have tried this, but the drawing in visula.RenderOpen is so slow that there is no smooth scrolling. But I found a solution. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:`visual.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Sub() DrawVisual)` is Awaitable. And so I used it with Await. (In `DrawVisual` RenderOpen is called) Now all DrawingVisuals are loaded faster and the UI isn't blocked any more. Thanks Visual Vincent and Scott for your posts.